# Navigating to a new page onClick of the item in React-data-table-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to navigate to new link when the user clicks on the row items, the link is framed dynamically based on the data of that row, i am using react-data-table-component and they have a prop called onRowClicked ,I am able to get the data of the row that is being pressed but I am not able to navigate to new page any idea on how to navigate?

what i have tried is :

```
    <DataTable
  columns={columns}
  data={rowData}
  onRowClicked={rowData => (
    <Redirect push to={`/admin/productspage/${rowData.shortName}`} />
  )}
  pointerOnHover={true}
  highlightOnHover={true}
  theme="light"
  customStyles={customStyles}
  striped={true}
/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Please Note : I do not have any history passed to component which is having react-data-table-component.

Comment: Please share some code for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not able to be redirected because you need to render your `<Redirect>` in your code so it can work properly.

For functional components (be sure to `import {useState} from 'React'`):

```
          const [redirState, setState] = useState(false);
          const [shortName, setData] = useState('');
          let redirecting = redirState ? (<Redirect push to={`/admin/productspage/${shortName}`}/>) : '';
          return (
              <DataTable
                columns={columns}
                data={rowData}
                onRowClicked={rowData => {
                  setState(true);
                  setData(rowData.shortName);
                  }}
                pointerOnHover={true}
                highlightOnHover={true}
                theme="light"
                customStyles={customStyles}
                striped={true}
              />
              {redirecting} 
              );
```

Comment: the parent is the react hook i.e functional component. Also how to you get the data for ${rowData.shortname} inside the render ? as you are saving only the boolean value in the state

Comment: I've updated the code for functional components using the data extracted from the component to the parent state